# DataGridTemplateColumn binding converter

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am using the following code :
Where is my mistake? What's the solution?

```
        <MyClass:CheckForVis  x:Key="_CheckForVis"/>

    </Window.Resources>
        <DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tempWin, Path=TitleClass}" >

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tempWin, Path=TitleClass,Converter={StaticResource _CheckForVis}}" Width="*" Header="Input" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  Name="partMojudi">
                                <TextBlock Width="Auto" Name="txtInput" Text="{Binding input}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid>

        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why not right? 
Where is my mistake? What's the solution?

Comment: You are not explaining what the problem is. This is completely unclear.

Comment: i think u didn't get anything on your datagrid because your binding is wrong.